# Dart correct padding for AES Key

Tags: dart, encryption, bouncycastle, pointycastle

I'm building a simple encryption tool in dart.

I need to encrypt my rsa private key with a pass phrase.

I'm using AES to do the encryption.

AES requires keys to be a specific no. of bits.

In my case 256 bits.

I'm requiring that the user enter a passphrase of at least 16 characters (128 bits).

As such I need to extend the passphrase to a full 256 bits.

Currently I just double the pass phrase and then clip the result to 256 bits.

Is this the correct thing to do or is the a more secure method of padding the key?

I'm using the dart pointycastle libraries which are based on the java bouncycastle libraries.

---

**Update**

Here is my latest attempt

```
class StrongKey extends Key {
  StrongKey.fromPassPhrase(String passPhrase) : super.fromUtf8(passPhrase);

  Key secureStretch(Uint8List salt) {
    return stretch(256, iterationCount: 100000, salt: salt);
  }

  @override
  Key stretch(int desiredKeyLength, {int iterationCount = 100, Uint8List salt}) {
    final params = Pbkdf2Parameters(salt, iterationCount, desiredKeyLength);
    final pbkdf2 = PBKDF2KeyDerivator(Mac('SHA-512/HMAC'))..init(params);

    return Key(pbkdf2.process(bytes));
  }

  static Uint8List get generateSalt => SecureRandom(256).bytes;
}
```

Comment: You'd use a password based key derivation function (PBKDF) such as a secure version of Argon2 or, indeed, PBKDF2. You'd need a high iteration count and store a salt with the encrypted RSA key. Of course, 16 characters doesn't contain even close to 128 bits of randomness, so using AES-256 is fooling yourself.

Comment: 16 * 8 = 128 or have I misunderstood the bitness. This is intended as the minimum pass phrase and the app recommends users use a higher no. of chars. If its not enough randomness then how do you utilise a reasonable passphrase to encrypt a private key?

Comment: when you say store the salt I assume that the salt needs to be stored in clear text as it needs to be used to decrypt the key? I assume I need to add the salt to the pass phrase in a similar manner used for password hashing.

Comment: The passphrase is not using 128 bits because a normal user would not utilize all 256 possible characters for each byte. Passphrases are inherently weak, that's one reason why you'd use a PBKDF. AES-128 seems sufficient, as it is not the weak spot. Yes, the salt just needs to be unique, but usually it's, say, a 16 **bytes** random value stored with the encrypted key.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I've updated the question with a class I found that looks like implements your suggestion. Can you confirm this looks OK?

Comment: The `from...` methods should be removed. The default iteration count is at least a factor of a thousand off, and the use of SHA-1 is not a good idea if you want to output 256 bits. For PBKDF2 you want to use a hash that can at least output as many bits as required (using SHA-512 instead is probably the best method to make sure that this is the case).

Comment: So to be clear the iteration should be 100,000.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I've posted an updated version of the Key generator which I believe follows your instructions.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'm probably pushing the love now, but this is what I'm trying to create.  https://github.com/bsutton/dvault/wiki  any feedback would be greatly appreciated.